# Load resource in a jar file Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, file, jar

I want to load a html file located in:

[image]

to use in standalone `spring boot` jar application.

This approach leads to `FileSystemNotFoundException`

```
new InputStreamReader(
          getClass().getResourceAsStream("/email-templates/html-email.html")
)
```

Using

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
...
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:email-templates/html-email.html");
```

leads to `NullPointerException`.

Could you please specify how to properly load a file in spring boot jar.

Comment: Why are you trying to manually load it instead of either using the `TemplateResolver` or injecting it (with `@Resource("classpath:email-templates/html-email.html")`, which would fail fast)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code. Using spring classpathresource you should be able to load them. As long as you try load this file inside spring context, Spring container is aware of its classpath .So it should load corresponding file.Otherwise , it tries to find in file system.

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("email-templates/html-email.html");
```

I assume you have these resouces in your jar, Check inside the jar file if those resources are present.

```
jar tf springboot.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

> Load resource in a jar file Java Spring

Try through below code.

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("email-templates/html-email.html");
```

`/email-templates/html-email.html`

If the above doesn't work visit this help full link
[Java ClassLoaderUtil](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ClassLoaderUtil.java/?v=source)

Comment: This one also leads to `FileSystemNotFoundException`.

Comment: Yes but also related to `FileSystems` , Also you can checkout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystemNotFoundException.html for better understanding.